# Why does S. R. S. Varadhan uses $\Phi$ as symbol for $\emptyset$

Tags: probability, measure-theory, soft-question

I've recently started studying some probability theory and looked through some books about this topic. In the first chapter of Probability Theory
by S. R. S. VaradhanI encountered

[image]

Why is the empty set denoted as $\Phi$? I do only know the symbol $\emptyset$. Are there any historical reasons for using $\Phi$? I do not really like this.

Comment: Probably just a  quirky personal preference.

Comment: The normal symbol should be $\varnothing$ anyway.

Comment: @Bernard Why $\varnothing$ over $\emptyset$?

Comment: See (comparatively) old books, say Bourbaki. I believe $\emptyset$ is a computer scientist, not a mathematician, notation.

Comment: This is not the only time I have seen $\Phi$ for the empty set.  My guess is that it was more common in the past than it is today.

Comment: If it's an older book (or a lightly-revised new edition of an older book) it may be that the typsetter did not have the symbol for null set available. And then there are people who just don't care about such distinctions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the picture I took from the [preview available at Google Books](https://books.google.it/books?id=jdGFAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=it#v=onepage&q&f=false)

[image]

The symbol is the standard one and I guess that your copy of the book has been obtained with poor OCR software.

I doubt that a book copyrighted in 2001 by the AMS is available as a free download.

Comment: I took a look at the physical copy of the book I have and it is indeed typeset as $\emptyset$.

Comment: @Batman In the `\varnothing` shape $\varnothing$

Comment: Yeah. (........)

Comment: Ah nice. Thanks a lot. I clicked on the first link provided by a google search using Probability Theory by S. R. S. Varadha. It seemed to me, since also an exam was there, that it is somehow related to the course the author teached.

Comment: At NYU, they have a version with $\Phi$ instead of $\emptyset$.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is a picture of the PDF version of the book at NYU, and there $\Phi$ is used as you can see.

[image]

The link to the PDF of the book is (see page 8)

[Copy of Probability at NYU](https://math.nyu.edu/%7Evaradhan/course/PROB.ch1.pdf)

My feeling is that a typist misread what Varadhan wrote by hand, and it remained in the book.  Since Varadhan is such an authority, the notation $\Phi$ spread in some math circles.  This is not the first time these kinds of things happen.  Just think of the "common knowledge" that spinach has large iron content.

Comment: This looks like a preprint, not the official edition (the typesetting is distinctly different). Perhaps the author used $\Phi$ in the preprint and the publisher changed to a more common symbol. Or it was a typing error.

Comment: Varadhan uses $\Phi$ throughout that preprint consistently, and that preprint is in his own home page at NYU. This might be the origin of the spreading of $\Phi$ as a symbol for the  empty set. It seems this is what students in India learn. It's even suggested that one should pronounce the symbol as 'phi': [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/empty-set/](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/empty-set/).

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was to suspect a typo, but he does seem to use this consistently.  It's certainly not standard notation.

Comment: I think that the link provided in the question provides a dubiously legal PDF obtained by OCR. In the Google Books preview the symbol is standard and I guess that it's the OCR software's fault.

Answer (score 0):

The empty set symbol $\varnothing$... I mean the empty set symbol $\emptyset$ is written quite similarly to the Greek letter $\phi$. And I have occasionally seen people use the capital version $\Phi$ instead, but it is rare.

FWIW, I could even imagine someone preferring $\Phi$ because it has very little chance of getting mixed up with zero; some people write zero as $\emptyset$ (to ensure that zero isn't confused with the letter $O$).

Comment: I think the origin of the $\emptyset$  notation is from computer science: most program listings use teletype fonts,, and it's the standard way to distinguish the digit `0` from  the letter `0`. Mathematicians use (should use) $\varnothing$.

Comment: @Bernard... No, I believe use of the Swedish letter Ø for the empty set precedes every computer language.

Comment: @GEdgar: That's precisely what I say. The notation `\emptyset`  *only* dates back to the age of computers (and should be avoided).

Comment: Obviously, \emptyset for $\emptyset$ is part of TeX, which was invented by Knuth.  Who invented \varnothing for $\varnothing$?